# Does AWS S3 charge requests for EC2 transfer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understood from the [pricing sheet](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) that data transfer is free between EC2 and S3 in the same region, but will I still be charged for GET, PUT etc. requests?

Comment: that's correct, I am not sure whether you need to use an S3 VPV endpoint to get the traffic free

Comment: @gusto2 didn't catch that. Is there some different mechanism to access S3 data locally? AWS novice here

Comment: see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/ there is a way to enable access from VPC to S3 without going through public network

Comment: Yes, you'll be charged for API calls (other than  DELETE). You don't need to use a VPC endpoint to access S3 in order for in-region data transfer to cost zero.

Comment: @jarmod I think that endpoints are needed when you have an instance in a non public subnet (has no route to an internet gateway) trying to access S3

Comment: @RenatoGama yes, if that were the case here (there’s no indication that it is) but that’s not relevant to the discussion of data transfer charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct -- there is **no Data Transfer charge** for traffic between Amazon EC2 instances and Amazon S3 within the same region. (The same goes for other services, too.)

However, these charges still apply:

- Storage pricing
- Request pricing